# Auto Populating the first instance of a nested form field in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

Using Ruby 2.3.3 and Rails 5.1.4

I have a form for users to fill out that uses the Nested Form Fields Gem to allow users to add a dynamic amount of Group Members. I would like to have the first instance already filled out and populated as current_user.email when the form is loaded

This is my class Group

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teammates, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teammates, allow_destroy: true
end
```

This is my form

```
<%= form_with(model: group, local: true) do |form| %>
<div class="form-group row">
  <%= form.nested_fields_for :teammates do |member| %>
      <div align="right" class="col-md-3">
       <label>Group Member: </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= member.text_field :email, placeholder: 'email', class: 'input' %>
        <%= member.remove_nested_fields_link %> <br />
      </div>
  <%end %>
  <%= form.add_nested_fields_link :teammates, '+ Add a Group Member', id: 'addGroupMember' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it's done like this

```
class GroupsController
  def edit
    @group.teammates.build(email: current_user.email)
  end
end
```

You only build a teammate object, it's not being saved yet. But it's enough for the form to see it and render itself correspondingly.